# Executing "strapi admin:reset-user-password" command on a Strapi app deployed on Render

Tags: deployment, command-line, render, strapi, production

I have a Strapi application deployed on Render, and I forgot the admin password for that so I probably need to run the npm run strapi-admin-rest command to perform certain tasks. However, I'm unsure how to execute this command in a production environment without direct access to the command line.

Could someone please provide guidance on how to run npm commands, specifically npm run strapi-admin-rest, on a Strapi app deployed on Render? Is there a way to achieve this through the Render dashboard or any other method? Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Tried exploring the onrender dashboard, I couldn't find any direct way to execute npm commands within the Render environment.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you are able to run commands on the server that runs your Strapi application on Render.

Something that you can do, is to click on Forgot password on the login page.
If you set an SMTP server (or third party provider) for sending email, you will receive an email to reset your password.

If it's not the case, still do the reset password stuff.
Then access your database, and in the `admin_users` table, in the `reset_password_token` column, you will see a value for your admin user
Then visit the page /admin/auth/reset-password?code= and add the token for the code param.

Then reset your password thanks to the form that will be displayed.